# Dynamic field add if not present in Elastic Search using Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Is it possible to add a new field dynamically in elastic search index on the go?
For example, i have an index with field `id`, `type`, `value`. Now there is a new field called `accept` which can contain boolean value. User search for an id and he got details, now they choose to accept this value so that field gets added in index saying `true`.

Now if we changed it. But in future if they wish to again make it `false` then they wouldn't have to again create a new column as it already exists.

I am not able to pull of this story. Not sure if it is possible.

Any insights would be appreciated!!

Comment: Are you looking or describing an update feature of Elasticsearch? If that is not the case, could you please elaborate a bit more. Elasticsearch creates a dynamic mapping(if you haven't created mapping) based on best guess on the values of each and every field you ingest. And if you again ingest the same document again, it would simply update that document and hence would update the values accordingly. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can we dynamically add on the go column in pre-existing Elastic search index with already created fields?

Comment: @TrickOrTreat Yes you can add a field to an index mapping before having values there. Use the `put_mapping` API to update your mapping with the new field included. 
See this discussion here for more info: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/adding-new-fields-to-an-existing-index/7397

Comment: okk...sounds good

Answer (score 0):

It was present all along. I just didn't notice.
This piece of code below, either adds dynamically a column or updates if already existed.

```
es.update(index='test-for-update',doc_type='MOL',id='WrQg5nIBulf73GCv-eDS',
                body={ "doc": {"accept": True} })
```